# The $n^{th}$ derivative of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

> **Question:**
>
> Prove that the $n$th derivative of $\sin^4 x+ \cos^4 x$ is $4^{n-1} 
> > \cos (4x+n\pi/2)$.

I tried to work on this problem by myself, but I don't know where to start. Any answers or hints appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Try starting with the $n=0$ case. (i.e. when you don't take the derivative at all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin^4x+\cos^4x=1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^22x=1-\frac{1-\cos4x}{4}=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\cos4x$$
Now, can you calculate the derivative?

Comment: I'll try, thanks